# Temporarily comment out <script> tag for debugging

Tags: javascript, html

Often while coding and debugging I might want to comment out a `<script>` tag.  An example might be when doing the following:

```
<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<!--script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script-->
```

I tend to add the new line instead of just changing the original to act as a reminder that I want to put that back before going live.  I got this syntax from a colleague but I had never seen this it before.  Is there a syntactically correct method to comment out `<script>` tags in HTML?

**EDIT:** I know there are lots of discussions about commenting out scripts in order to hide them from older browsers but that is not what I am doing.  I am wanting to hide the tag completely.

Comment: Are you using any server-side technology, or just client-side?

Comment: Tons of alternatives – so much so that I think this is opinion based. My opinion is that (having a version control system) you should just delete the line, and if you want it back, it's in version history.

Comment: @kojiro, I have updated to be more specific

Comment: Syntactically correct, no, because there's nothing syntactically wrong with what you're already doing. There are other ways to include different scripts in production vs development, but we'd need to know a lot more about your environment to suggest anything in that direction.

Comment: Are you just asking what an HTML comment tag is? Because `<!-- -->` is the syntactically-correct HTML comment tag.

Comment: @ajp15243, no.  I know what an HTML comment is.  The `<script>` was being hidden in my question above which is now fixed.  Although according to your answer, it doesn't change much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to dynamically load your scripts in, given a debug flag. For example:

**Markup:**

```
<script src="lib/include.js"></script>
```

**include.js**

```
var IS_DEBUG = true;

if(IS_DEBUG) {
    loadScript("jquery.js");
    loadScript("anotherscript.js");
}
else {
    loadScript("jquery.min.js");
    loadScript("anotherscript.min.js");
}

function loadScript(name) {
    var elem = document.createElement("script");
    elem.src = name;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elem);
}
```

That means you can just toggle the `IS_DEBUG` flag to load in the required scripts. This is a very rudimentary example, but you get the idea. You might even be able to tie this in with something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I would certainly use this method if it were up to me but the guy I am working for is a stickler for using the least amount of code for a task.  I'm certain he would balk at this although require.js might be a good alternative.  Thx.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted this answer because my picky boss aside, this is a good solution and one I have used before.